# Longest Subsequence where an integer in the output is 5 times greater than the previous

Tags: java, adhoc

I'm practicing with UVA problems and I'm stuck in this. I need to get the longest [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) where the consecutive integers are 5 times greater than the previous

sample input: 7, 100, 3, 80, 3, 5, 18, 25, 73, 125
output: 3 (5, 25, 125)

I thought of a solution but it will take n^n where I compare an integer with the rest of the integers, which is not ideal. is it possible for a faster solution?

Comment: what do you mean by consecutive integers? In your example 5,25,125 are not consecutive. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i mean the next digit is 5 times greater than the previous

Comment: I don't know how you arrive at n^n. Should be doable in n^2.

Comment: my solution includes taking a value and comparing it to the rest of the values. how can i do this in n^2?

Comment: *[`consecutive`](https://www.google.com/search?q=consecutive): following continuously, in **unbroken** or logical sequence.* The numbers *5*, *25*, *125* are not **consecutive** in the sequence 7, 100, 3, 80, 3, *5*, **18**, *25*, **73**, *125*

Comment: i have edited the problem to clearly explain what needs to be accomplished

Comment: You're confusing ^ with *.

Comment: Should the subsequence be in the same order as the input? What if the input was changed so that 125 came before 25, would you still expect the longest subsequence to be 5,25,125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you traverse the list and build up a map of the values seen so far, mapped to the length the sequence ending in that number, you can solve the problem in *O(n)*.

Given your sample list of `7, 100, 3, 80, 3, 5, 18, 25, 73, 125`, the resulting map would be:

```
7   → 1    ⇐ Not divisible by 5, so length=1
100 → 1    ⇐ 100 / 5 = 20, but 20 hasn't been seen, so length=1
3   → 1    ⇐ Not divisible by 5, so length=1
80  → 1    ⇐ 80 / 5 = 16, but 16 hasn't been seen, so length=1
3          ⇐ Skipped since 3 already in map
5   → 1    ⇐ 5 / 5 = 1, but 1 hasn't been seen, so length=1
18  → 1    ⇐ Not divisible by 5, so length=1
25  → 2    ⇐ 25 / 5 = 5, and 5 has length 1, so length=2
73  → 1    ⇐ Not divisible by 5, so length=1
125 → 3    ⇐ 125 / 5 = 25, and 25 has length 3, so length=3
```

Longest sequence is 3, ending in value 125. We can now build the sequence by reverse-calculating it: 125 → 25 → 5

Here is the code (not using Java 8 features):

```
private static void printLongestTimesFiveSequence(int ... input) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> valueLengthMap = new HashMap<>();
    int longestLength = 0, longestValue = 0;
    for (int value : input) {

        // Find length of sequence ending in 'value'
        int length = 1;
        if (value % 5 == 0) {
            Integer prevLength = valueLengthMap.get(value / 5);
            if (prevLength != null)
                length += prevLength;
        }

        // If length is new longest sequence, remember it
        if (length > longestLength) {
            longestLength = length;
            longestValue = value;
        }

        // Remember length of sequence ending in 'value' if first time seen,
        // or if longer than previously seen (e.g. for 15, 3, 15)
        Integer currentLength = valueLengthMap.get(value);
        if (currentLength == null || currentLength < length)
            valueLengthMap.put(value, length);
    }

    // Build sequence ending in value of remembered longest sequence
    int[] sequence = new int[longestLength];
    for (int i = longestLength - 1, value = longestValue; i >= 0; i--, value /= 5)
        sequence[i] = value;

    // Print result
    System.out.println(longestLength + " " + Arrays.toString(sequence));
}
```

*Test*

```
printLongestTimesFiveSequence(7, 100, 3, 80, 3, 5, 18, 25, 73, 125);
printLongestTimesFiveSequence(10, 50, 2);
printLongestTimesFiveSequence(15, 3, 75, 15, 75);
printLongestTimesFiveSequence(4, 20, 100, 20, 100);
printLongestTimesFiveSequence(5, 25, 125, 25, 125);
printLongestTimesFiveSequence();
```

*Output*

```
3 [5, 25, 125]
2 [10, 50]
3 [3, 15, 75]
3 [4, 20, 100]
3 [5, 25, 125]
0 []
```

Comment: Hold on a second.... you've got the length and entry point to the longest subsequence already, if this is O(n log n), does that mean that by building an arraylist (insert cost is amortised constant time) of the previous entries in the subsequence as the value for the map, this could approach O(n)? Each time a subsequence becomes longer we can discard the smaller subsequence, take its list, add a value to the end, and put it back into the map with a new key. Map lookups are constant, list addition is constant...  Somebody should check my work, but I think this can be done in linear time O(n).

Comment: @SeanReilly Sorry, I was thinking of `get()` / `put()` performance of a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is *O(log n)*. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is *O(1)*, so this solution is *O(n)*.

Comment: You also don't need the `Build sequence ending in value of remembered longest sequence phase`, if the value of the map is List<Integer> instead of Integer. You can just store the existing subsequence and then replace it with a longer one by appending to the list (and swapping the key the list is mapped to).

Comment: @Sean Sure, each map value could be a list of the sequence ending in the value of the key, but that's a lot of extra memory, for no gain, since the sequence can easily be built after the iteration. --- I don't understand the "swapping the key the list is mapped to" part of your comment.

Comment: You don't need to build the entire list every time you find a new entry in a subsequence. You can just reuse the existing list from the previous entry in the subsequence and append an additional value to it. This list needs to be mapped to the new entry in the sequence, and it no longer needs to be mapped to any other entries in the sequence. The value (the list) doesn't change, although it is modified. The key does change. Hence "swapping the key". It might be a clumsy way to describe it.

Comment: @SeanReilly But you don't want to remove the old key, because it may be seen again, and you'd need to know. And you can't "share" the list between keys, because an earlier key may be revised. Example: `10, 50, 1, 5, 10, 5`. The second 10 will be `3 [1, 5, 10]`, but 50 will stay `2 [10, 50]`. Anyway, as I said, you can do lists in the map, but I chose to keep the map simple, but having to "backfill" the sequence at the end, instead of a more complex map using memory for lists that won't be use, but not needing "backfill". Either way works, that was just my choice.

Comment: ah yes. I hadn't considered the same number appearing twice in the original sequence. It will still work however — when the second 10 arrives there won't be a value mapped to 10 any more (it having been already remapped to 50). But on balance it's probably just more complicated for this problem, as you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

As the solution need only give *one* best solution, one can drop some partial solutions. Such solutions always go with some fine data model crystalized from the requirements.
Suppose you have upto an index `i` maintained all possible subsequences upto `i - 1`.

From those subsequences only the last item (*tail*) is of interest.

1. The item can start a new sequence only if it cannot added to an existing sequence (and 3. there is no sequence with tail <= item).
2. Where possible a sequence can add the item to form an additional new sequence
3. A shorter sequence should have a tail lesser than those of longer sequences

Point 3 is interesting as it means that for every length of those sequences you only need 1 sequence, with the lowest tail.

```
Sequence[] sequencesByLength = new Sequence[n];
// sequencesByLength[i] < sequencesByLength[j] <=> i < j
```

For a new item one can do a binary search for item/5 in the range 0 .. highest sequnce index < i.
Say you could add it on position k, then a new sequence could be added to k+1, when k+1's tail was >= item.

So `O(n.log n)`.